# Query WHERE clause and JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having an issue using a WHERE clause and JOIN.

```
SELECT * FROM `CallDetailRecord` 
  WHERE `StartTime` >=1357102799000 
  AND `StartTime` <=1357880399000 
  JOIN `CallEvent` ON `EventID` = `CallEventID`
```

> Error Code: 1064
>   
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL       server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN `CallEvent` ON `EventID` = `CallEventID`
>   
> LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 1

```
Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.004 sec
---------------------------------------------------
```

I'm just trying to limit data set by time "starttime', but I get query error and it refers to
join.

Any ideas? I will be happy to provide more info if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your original query

```
SELECT * FROM `CallDetailRecord`
WHERE `StartTime` >=1357102799000
AND `StartTime` <=1357880399000
JOIN `CallEvent` ON `EventID` = `CallEventID`
LIMIT 1000
```

In theory, you can do the following

- Subquery that has WHERE on the StartTime
- Add ORDER BY StartTime
- Do the LIMIT inside the subsquery
- Specify a LEFT JOIN

Here is such a query

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM `CallDetailRecord`
    WHERE `StartTime` >=1357102799000
    AND `StartTime` <=1357880399000
    ORDER BY StartTime
    LIMIT 0,1000
) A LEFT JOIN `CallEvent` B ON `EventID` = `CallEventID`;
```

If the query is slow, then add an index on StartTime

```
ALTER TABLE CallDetailRecord ADD INDEX (StartTime);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thank you, it works but it is very slow, maybe because it is sub query?

Comment: Is StartTime indexed ???

Comment: okay add index and try

Comment: Did the index on StartTime help ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `WHERE` clause must be after your join, perhaps?

```
SELECT * 
FROM CallDetailRecord
    JOIN CallEvent ON EventID = CallEventID
WHERE StartTime >= 1357102799000 AND StartTime <=1357880399000
```

Note: You may want to prefix the fields with table names or aliases...